Google Workspace users for authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5 apps
Is it possible to setup authentication via my organization's Google Workspace users?
I have several ASP.NET MVC 5 web apps that I want to protect via Google's Workspace users authentication.
Link to any article for above use case will be appreciated.
